# How can add html base URL for the particular Div section using PHP?

Tags: php, html

```
<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
```

How can i add the above base URL for the particular div section using php like

If i have two div section

This section links will work with above base URl link

```
<div>
<a href="/help">help</a>
</div>
```

This section links will work with websites URl link

```
<div>
<a href="/help">help</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying "simple html dom" to fetch some content from some other website paste it under one div section that has relative links. That can be converted to direct link like "/images/image.png" to "www.example.com/images/image.png"

Comment: please post your desired output.your question is unclear.

Comment: There is no such concept in html. You either have to code URLs instead of relative links or you have to alter the references dynamically using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class='normalUrl'>
    <a href="/help">Help</a>
</div>

<div class='otherBaseUrl'>
    <a href="<?php print('http://some.otherwebsite.com'); ?>/help">Help</a>
</div>
```

This is a hardcoded way just to show how the end result can be achieved. I'm sure you want to make this more generic to fit your goal.

Comment: I'm trying "simple html dom" to fetch some content from some other website paste it under one div section that has relative links. That can be converted to direct link like "/images/image.png" to "www.example.com/images/image.png"

Comment: you already know what page you are on, considering you made the request to 'download' that page to parse it. You give your returned HTML to another function `correct_urls($html, $baseurl);`. Just set your `$baseurl` to the link you initially cURL'd, and you're good to go. -- This, assuming that you are doing all of this before rendering the page (PHP), and not with JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this directly with html. You can do it with some server side languages like PHP like following.

```
<a href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>">abc</a>
<a href="<?php echo $current_url; ?>">abc</a>
```

or

You can also do it with javascript ( client side )

Comment: I'm trying "simple html dom" to fetch some content from some other website paste it under one div section that has relative links. That can be converted to direct link like "/images/image.png" to "www.example.com/images/image.png"