# Changing the Base URL for crawled links

Tags: php, html, web-crawler, simple-html-dom, base-tag

I am crawling links from some websites with Simple HTML DOM, however I have run into the problem that many websites use relative links instead of the full URL.

So what happens is that I crawl the links, and output them directly onto my website, but each link leads to *www.mydomain.com/somearticle* instead of *www.crawleddomain.com/somearticle*.

I have done some digging and I found out about the [BASE tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag). Since I am crawling from multiple sites, I cannot just set a base tag for my website, because it will change from output to output. So I was searching to have a base tag only for a certain div. I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653959/how-can-add-html-base-url-for-the-particular-div-section-using-php).

However, I tried manually including the base url like below, but that did not work:

```
echo ('http://www.baselink.com/' . strip_tags($post, '<p><a>'));
```

I also tried the second option, with the `correct_urls($html, $baseurl);` function, but apparently that does not exist.

Is there any way to change the base URL (or append it) to the relative URLs in a for-loop in PHP?

[Here is the output](http://globalsocialnews.com/crawler/test8.php)

And here is the code I am using:

```
<div class='rcorners1'>
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$target_url = "http://www.buzzfeed.com/trending?country=en-us";

$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file($target_url);

$posts = $html->find('ul[class=list--numbered trending-posts trending-posts-now]');
$limit = 10;
$limit = count($posts) < $limit ? count($posts) : $limit;
for($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++){
  $post = $posts[$i];
  $post->find('div[class=trending-post-text]',0)->outertext = "";
  echo strip_tags ($post, '<p><a>');  
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [a library that converts relative hrefs to absolute](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/phpuri)

Then do something like:

```
include_once('phpuri.php');

$uri = phpUri::parse($target_url);

foreach($html->find('a[href]') as $a){
  $a->href = $uri->join($a->href);
}
```